# Signing mac application failed

Tags: macos, certificate, packagemaker

I have ".pkg" file that I'm trying to sign with Apple. The pkg include 2 ".app" files and 2 executable files.
I'm trying to sign it as an **mac** application (**not an iOS**). I got 5 certificates from apple:

> Mac Development
>
> Mac App Distribution
>
> Mac Installer Distribution
>
> Developer ID Application
>
> Developer ID installer

and add them all to KeyChain access.

Now I need to sign it.
I look at this guide:
http://successfulsoftware.net/2012/08/30/how-to-sign-your-mac-os-x-app-for-gatekeeper/
and the signing was not succed. when I'm trying to install my app I get the warning "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority".

I also added "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" cert to the KeyChain.

I tried to find guide in apple developer site but nothing was helpful.

Does anyone can help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not sign it as an app. (The link shows you how to sign an app).
You must use "`Developer ID Installer`" certificate to sign "`.pkg`" files.
Use following command:

```
productsign --sign "Your certificate name" "path_to_unsigned.pkg" "signed_output.pkg"
```

Make sure you have added the certificate to the keychain. It should be visible there as something like "`Developer ID Installer:company_name`" This should be your certificate name in above command.

Some useful links:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productsign.1.html

http://macinstallers.blogspot.in/2012/06/creating-packages-for-mac.html